# What is the difference in RBAC for VMs vs VM scale sets?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-rbac

I have a custom role that allows creation of a VM in a particular VNet and its subnet. I am able to deploy a single VM in this subnet without issue. However, when I try to deploy a scale set to the same subnet, I am faced with the following error:

```
Missing write permissions {'Microsoft.Network/VirtualNetworks/subnets/write'} for the following subnet(s):'MySubnet'
```

The role granting access to the VNet has `Join Virtual Network`. Why does this permission allow a VM deployment and not a scale set deployment? Is there a difference in RBAC between deploying a VM and VM scale set?

**Edit**: Added role definitions

The VNet has RBAC with a custom network contributor role granting the following

```
"permissions": [
      {
        "actions": [
          "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/join/action",
          "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
          "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/write",
          "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/*/join/action",
          "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/write",
          "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/write",
          "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/delete"
        ],
        "dataActions": [],
        "notActions": [],
        "notDataActions": []
      }
    ]
```

The RBAC on the resource group grants the following

```
"permissions": [
      {
        "actions": [
          "*",
          "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/*",
          "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/*"
        ],
        "dataActions": [],
        "notActions": [
          "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Delete",
          "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Write",
          "Microsoft.Authorization/elevateAccess/Action",
          "Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/write",
          "Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/delete",
          "Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/*/write",
          "Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/*/delete",
          "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/write",
          "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/delete",
          "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/peer/action",
          "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write",
          "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/delete"
        ],
        "notDataActions": []
      }
    ]
```

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can accept it. Or for more help please let me know.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT Updated my post with RBAC definitions. I am still unable to create the scale set

Comment: What way do you use t set up the permission? Template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Scale sets are built from virtual machines. With scale sets, the
>   management and automation layers are provided to run and scale your
>   applications.

So there is no difference in RBAC between deployment a VM and VM Scale Set. And the result of the test here:

[image]

According to the ERROR you posted, there is no write permission of the subnet. I think you should check the account that you have used. If you use the RBAC for the Vnet, the Contributor permission is necessary at least.

You can get more details about the Differences between virtual machines and scale sets from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview#differences-between-virtual-machines-and-scale-sets).